# Phone failed to appear in device list in MSVC 2013

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

Well, I have a Microsoft account that I have used when I was installing Windows 8 on my PC. That is usual, non-developer account. Now I want to begin development for Windows Phone using real device. My boss has purchased a licence and gave me login/password to paid Developer Account. I have used that paid account to register a phone device. I can see device connected in File Explorer. And I can see device registered in Developer Dashboard. But I cannot see it in MSVC 2013's combo-box. I can only see a list of emulators.

I guess I have to switch my Microsoft account to that that paid Account on my PC, but I don't know how to do it. Or maybe Microsoft uses something like Developer certificates or provisions as Apple does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can switch to different account in visual stodion 2012 see at the top right of the VS2013 expand your current account and click account Settings.. and from the next dialog sign out and sign in with different account.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No you could find an option called device with the set of the emulators in your combo box?

Don't you?

You don't need anything, you just need to have the VS completely installed.